# Can anyone help identify this artist and translate writing?

Tags: translation, character-identification

I am hoping someone can you help translate/identify the artist seal and secondary seal on this painting. Can you also translate the writing at the top as well please?

It was a gift from an investor to my prior real estate company and then given to me by my Director years later.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st pic: 屈鈞之印, roughly “the seal of 屈 (surname) 鈞 (given name)

2nd pic: 龍騰虎躍, roughly “dragons rising and tigers leaping”

3rd pic: 馬到**成功** [the common verse is 馬到功成, i’m not sure it’s a typo, or written deliberately] , roughly “The horse reaches, the work to succeed”, or “to instantly succeed”

丁丑秋月屈鈞畫, roughly “drawn by 屈鈞 in the autumn of 1997 / 1937 . . .”

generally, the picture would be called “八駿圖” (the picture of 8 fine horses); btw, the digit “8” sounds similar to “發” (prosperous); that,
such picture is a quite good souvenir for business

have fun :)

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know if Qu Jun is a well known artist?

Comment: i don’t know lah 